# DB25M to DB26M pinout

Tags: connector, pinout

I am trying to connect a DB25 male cable to a DB26 male receptable.

Seems that there are no out of the box adapters available for this, so will have to solder my own.

Having trouble and a lot of confusion on how to make the correct connections, so that's why I'm basically looking for a correct wiring diagram. (seeing some weird diagrams with crossing cables etc on a google search).

**Some additional context:**

I am currently building the open source https://opensfx.com/ project

This means that I have no possiblity to change the plugs / receptables on both the arduino and the servo motors, they come as-is.

Normally, the servo controllers come with a DB25 connector and simply connecting with a DB25 male to DB25 male cable is enough. However, my servo controller currently has a DB26 connector, hence it is incompatible with what I would like to achieve. I have seen forum posts that people were able to connect the DB26 to their breakout board though, but they didn't specify how.

It should simply be a matter of adapting a DB25M to DB25M cable towards a DB25M to DB26 cable by attaching the correct pins.

**Pinouts:**

Pinout servo controller side (DB26 female):

I am using the Mige MG-DS100S-75 servo controller for the Mige 90ST-M02430 servo motor. ([link to manual](https://www.xsimulator.net/community/attachments/ds100s-manual-pdf.57368/)), however the most important part is the pinout in the following picture
[image: Pinout servo controller]

Pinout Arduino breakout board (DB25 female):

Reference:
https://opensfx.com/build-process-controller-wiring/

*note: I am not using the default breakout connectors in the pictures, I am using the open source [breakout board](https://github.com/Pyronious/SFX-100-Breakout-Board) created by Pyroneus, however this is just a PCB version of all the wiring displayed in the wiring diagram, therefore you can see this breakout board as a simplification*

[image: Pinout arduino side]

Comment: Is your problem about what the connections should be eg pin X to pin Y? Or is the problem identifying which pin is which *physically*? Or something else? Also, the exact wiring may depend on *why* you need to make this adapter - have you got details of the two devices and the signals you are trying to connect?

Comment: what part is confusing? the diagram or the pin number locations? or the DB25M vs F to DB26M

Comment: or is this a shared data splitter? https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=COMTROL+Rocketport+Cable&dc&linkCode=g13&qid=1561387163&tag=avtechmediaam-20&ref=aw_s_fkmr0

Comment: @SamGibson 
Updated my question with more info

Comment: Thanks for the added info: "*Attaching servo motor controllers to an Arduino breakout board using DB25 female connectors.*" So you list the signals on each pin of the DB25 connectors; you do the same for the DB26 connectors; then you make a list of what connections you want to make (assuming you are *sure* that the signals are compatible between the two ends of the cable). Where in the process are you stuck *exactly*? Please add links in the question for the data sheets of the servo motor controller and the Arduino breakout board which you are trying to connect.

Comment: @SamGibson updated the question with the respective pinouts on both ends. Basically I am stuck how the connections on my cable should be

Comment: First you need to develop a thorough understanding of the electrical signaling.  One of your pieces appears to be differential, the other single ended.  Sometimes you can connect a single ended signal and ground, other times you cannot.  And the voltages may or may not be compatible.  What you have is an electrical interfacing problem before it is a connector problem.

Comment: @Dennis - Thanks. However (a) you didn't supply the **links** to the data sheets that I requested, so we still can't see all necessary details; (b) I'm not convinced (from the limited info so far) that the two devices are compatible. Do you have specific confirmation from somewhere that this specific Arduino breakout board and this specific servo motor controller *are* compatible? If so, please add the link to that confirmation. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson updated again for completeness

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a DB25 connector where a 26-conductor ribbon cable is crimped onto the back, and then the board end you crimp on a 2x13 female connector and plug in onto male pins.
Here are examples  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/d-sub-connectors/439?k=25+Dsub&k=&pkeyword=25+Dsub&sv=0&pv589=265&sf=1&FV=ffe001b7%2C160002f&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: That's not remotely going to work, as these *unrelated* pieces of equipment don't put the signals in the same physical places / pin numbers.  It's not even entirely clear that just wire in *any* configuration will solve the problem, at least without some more in-depth understanding as one of the pieces appears to expect differential signals, which may or may not work with a single ended signal and ground.